# Refreshing Data Group in flex immidiately

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder4.5

I am using custom item-renderer to render items of my **DataGroup**.
The problems is whenever the value of data-provider(Arraylist in my case) is changed,
it takes 6-9 seconds to render, which is unacceptable.

When I tried to back-track the problem, I found that whenever there's less amount of data, DataGroup is refreshed immediately and all the items are rendered within a second.

But whenever there is relatively more amount of data, DataGroup takes 5-7 seconds to get refreshed.

This is my data group :

```
<s:DataGroup id="selectedInstancesView" dataProvider="{relatedInstances}" width="100%" height="100%"
            itemRenderer="com.ui.renderers.CustomInstanceRenderer"
            clipAndEnableScrolling="true" >
```

This is the function which re-assigns the value to data-provider of above data group :

```
private function relatedInstanceRetrieved(event:ResultEvent):void{
    trace("related instances retrieved at :: " + new Date());
    relatedInstances = new ArrayList(event.result as Array);
    trace("related instances populated at :: " + new Date());
}
```

And This is within my custom-item-renderer class, where I am printing the time on creation-complete of item-renderer :

```
protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    trace("getting rendered at :: " + new Date());      }
```

And this is the result I am getting :

```
related instances retrieved at :: Wed Apr 20 **20:58:10** GMT+0530 2016

related instances populated at :: Wed Apr 20 **20:58:10** GMT+0530 2016

getting rendered at :: Wed Apr 20 **20:58:15** GMT+0530 2016

getting rendered at :: Wed Apr 20 20:58:15 GMT+0530 2016

getting rendered at :: Wed Apr 20 20:58:15 GMT+0530 2016

...(1000 similar traces with exact same time)
```

All the item-renderers (around 1000) are created within a second.

But if you see, the time at which
Data-Provider (relatedInstances) is re-populated or re-assigned
and
the time at which the item-renderers start getting created is **5** seconds, which means it is taking 5 seconds to refresh the data, which is not acceptable.

I tried using invalidateDisplayList(); reassigning the item renderer, and invalidateProperties() methods, But none worked.

I am using flex sdk 4.6

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Are you sure you are using reusable item renderer. I doubt because it shouldn't list out 1000 trace if reusable renderer are used.

Comment: @SameerJain Do I need to set some property to make item-renderer reusable ? Because I read somewhere that it's the flex which does something in the background to make it reusable.

Comment: Yeah by default it set to reused. But I was wondering perhaps you've turned it off. It can be controlled by useVirtualLayout property.

Comment: No, I haven't set such property

Comment: Please provide more info with your datagroup setup. I tried 1000 items in arraycollection with virtuallayout and it dont render all the items together.

Comment: Is relatedInstances bindable ? Have you tried to remove the dataProvider="{relatedInstances}" from your DataGroup component, remove the bindable from the relatedInstances and assign the dataprovider manually in your relatedInstanceRetrieved method ?

Comment: @Philarmon Hi, I just tried what you said, but it din't work as well. The other thing I am not getting is why still 1000 traces are being printed when flex is supposed to create only few item renderer at a time?